# Shortest route with fewest turns

Tags: java, algorithm, nodes, dijkstra

I had a requirement to generate shortest route. The first solution which suited my requirement was Dijkstra's algorithm, and hence I implemented the same (Java). Later, I had to modify the implementation to generate the shortest route "with least number of turns". After some head-scratching, i came up with a solution, although with a lot of conditions added into the existing Dijkstra's algorithm implementation. Now my query is, is there a better approach for this problem(like, any existing algorithm which already does this)? My solution includes storing additional turns information in each of the nodes in the route calculation iteration, and use the same while back-tracking the route.

Comment: What does "shortest route with the least number of turns" mean? In most cases, the shortest route and the route with the least number of turns will be different. Does it mean that among all the (equally short) shortest routes, you should choose the one with the least number of turns?

Comment: By "shortest route with the least number of turns", i mean, if from point A to point B, there are multiple routes with same distance , priority should be given to the one with least number of turns. The route generated should always be the shortest, so even if there is a slightly longer route with lesser turns, that is not a candidate. This may not be a user scenario outdoors, but indoors like inside an office, it will be more useful

Comment: Both the solutions work fine. My existing solution was very similar to Aasmund's solution. But solution suggested by @sprinter is a more cleaner and scale-able approach I believe. Hence accepting his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately path finding algorithms are designed to find the lowest cost path. The definition of cost depends on the scenario. In one scenario cost might be distance but in other scenarios it might include terrain, slope, tolls etc. In your case the easiest way to model 'shortest route with least number of turns' is to derive cost from both distance and number of turns. In other words, include a cost for turning.

For example, if you are using the [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm, your cost calculation between two nodes could include a cost for the distance and an additional cost if this move requires a change of direction. If a different path does not require a change of direction then it will be lower cost and the algorithm will choose that path.

The only tricky thing here will be to keep the context of the previous moves to detect the turns. In A* you are generally keeping references back to the previous node so it should be fairly straightforward to decide if the next move requires a turn.

Comment: Yes. That sounds the way to go. But my doubt is, for ex, i define the cost=(distance + turn). I increase the cost by 0.5 units for every turn for example. In this case, if the cost to reach a node is 6units, there can be multiple routes with cost 4+(0.5*4) or 5+(0.5*2) [distance + number of turns*cost per turn]. According to this approach, both paths have same cost but there is an actual shorter path, the one with 4units distance.

Comment: @Ashwin in that case you can make the cost per turn .000001 (or something similar). That way the shortest distance will always win with least turns only used to distinguish between two paths of the same length.

Comment: Then @sprinter, I assume this is based on the condition that the cost for a turn should be very less compared to cost of any practical distance between two nodes. I cant think of any scenario which will fail according to this solution. Will try this out..

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need any backtracking or substantial tweaks to Dijkstra. Simply keep track (as you do), for each node, of the least number of turns on the currently shortest route to that node. Whenever you relax an edge, if the resulting path is equally short as the currently shortest route, you pick the one with the fewest turns.

---

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, this approach disregards the fact that the direction of the incoming edge of the chosen route affects the number of turns for the subsequent path. That will be fixed by storing in each node the shortest distance+turns *for each incoming edge* or *for each unique incoming angle* (however you measure that).

Alternatively, in order to get by with fewer modifications of Dijkstra, you can modify the graph beforehand: Split each node into one node per incoming edge (so that each resulting node has only one of the original node's incoming edges), but copy all the outgoing edges so that each resulting node has all the outgoing edges of the original node (each of which must be directed to the appropriate copy of the node at the other end of the edge). You might see that some of the resulting nodes have multiple incoming edges, but in that case, the nodes on the other ends of those edges are all copies of the same original node and thus represent the "same" original edge - therefore, each outgoing edge can be unambiguously labeled with whether that edge represented a turn out of that node (relative to the node's incoming edges) or not. Note that the best path in the original graph will still exist in the new graph (and no better paths will have been introduced). Now, Dijkstra just needs to be modified to track the number of turns associated with the shortest path to each node. Whenever an edge from *u* to *v* is relaxed and the candidate path is as short as the shortest path you have previously found for *v*, compare *u*'s turn count plus the edge's turn count (0 or 1 depending on whether the edge constituted a turn) to *v*'s turn count, and use that as a tiebreaker.

Comment: This approach may not work for all scenarios. For ex conside relow path
   A-----------------D
   |                       |
   B-----------------C----------E
While generating route from A to E, when we reach C in iteration, both paths, ABC and ADC are of same distance and same number of turns from A. But while backtracking, path ABCE seems better choice than ADCE, since former path does not add a turn at C but latter does add. 

So the path with least number of turns can only be found while backtracking i feel.

Comment: Is there an (literature-)algorithm for the splitting up of the nodes?

Comment: @Ruirui: I don't have my textbooks at hand, so for now, all I can tell you is that this is a pretty standard trick in algorithmic programming contests.

Comment: @Ruirui: Here's a different situation in which a similar trick can be employed: Given a graph in which two of the nodes are labeled S and T, find as many non-intersecting paths between S and T as possible (except that the paths necessarily will intersect in S and T). If we turn the graph into a flow graph by making the capacity of each edge 1, a maximum flow algorithm (like Edmonds-Karp) will be able to find as many paths as possible that do not share edges, but they might still intersect in the nodes.

Comment: @Ruirui: We can avoid intersection in the nodes of the original graph by creating a new graph in which avoiding edge intersection will avoid node intersection in the original graph. In this case, it is sufficient to split each node into two: one receives all the incoming edges, and one has all the outgoing ones. Then, we add a capacity-1 edge between the two. For each pair of "incoming/outgoing nodes" (each of which represents one node in the original graph), the algorithm will at most pick one path through the connecting edge.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Thank you for your replies, I really appreciate them :) In the last few days I have tried different approaches for the splitting-up and none of them worked correctly, I also did some research on the internet, but I didn't manage finding an algorithm (perhaps I just didn't get the keywords right). Thus, I would be really happy if you could maybe elaborate a little bit more on the splitting-up algorithm or send me a link to a resource that explains it.

Comment: @Ruirui: Which problem are you trying to solve? The one stated by the OP? I don't know if there is a standard name for that problem. The one I described in my comments is a special case of the _vertex-disjoint paths_ problem. Googling led to e.g. http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~sgk/papers/ufp-survey-2016-ss.pdf, where they state that "directed vertex-disjoint paths reduce to directed edge-disjoint paths by replacing every vertex with a pair of new vertices connected by an edge", and they reference https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895685710064 for specifics.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset I mean this procedure: "Alternatively, in order to get by with fewer modifications of Dijkstra, you can modify the graph beforehand: Split each node into one node per incoming edge, so that each node has only one of the incoming edges, but copy all the outgoing edges so that each node has all the original outgoing edges. The best path in the original graph will still exist in the new graph (and no better paths will have been introduced), and there is only one incoming angle in each node." Do you know an algorithm for that?

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset I found it especially difficult to program an algorithm that does the procedure with a rather complicated graph like this: A<->D; D<->B; D<->C; C<->J (where A<->B denotes a bidirectional edge between A and B). The thing with this graph is that D needs to be split into 3 subnodes and one of them has indegree > 1 because of the connectivity with C which has to be broken down as well.

Comment: @Ruirui: I have clarified my answer a bit. The situation you describe is valid: both of the incoming edges to _Dc_ (the copy of _D_ that exists for the purpose of receiving the edge from _C_) are coming from the two copies of _C_, and so they represent the same original edge. In particular, any path through _Dc_ has the property that it must have come from (one of the copies of) _C_, and so for every edge out of _Dc_, you know unambiguously whether that edge constitutes a turn or not.

Comment: @Ruirui: I now have my textbooks at hand, and finally found the reference I had been thinking of: Competitive Programming by Steven Halim and Felix Halim. In my copy (which was a preprint handed to me by the authors at a programming contest, so it doesn't say which edition it is), it's at the end of Section 4.6.5 "Other Applications [of Network Flow]". An early edition is available online at the authors' website: https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/myteaching/competitive_programming/cp1.pdf - look under "Max Flow with Vertex Capacities" on page 84.

Comment: @Ruirui: Quoting from the above reference: "To solve this variant, we can use the vertex splitting technique. A graph with a vertex weight can be converted into a more familiar graph without a vertex weight by splitting the vertex v to v_out and v_in, reassigning incoming edges to v_out / outgoing edges to v_in, and putting
the original vertex v’s weight as the weight of edge (v_out, v_in)."

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, why no one else has stated this and why there is an accepted answer.

The problem you are trying to solve (i.e., generate the shortest route with least number of turns) is an example of the *weight-constrained shortest path problem*.
It is therefore NP-Complete and cannot be solved efficiently.

You can find papers that discuss solving this problem e.g. http://web.stanford.edu/~shushman/math15_report.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple heuristic. Like others have pointed out, heuristic is the game in AStar.

```
if (Cost > CanMaxMove) Heuristic += 1000;
// for cost per grid pt typically 10 to 30
// Cost = PtCost + CostSoFar
// higher is worse (more costly)
```

You simply find the best path as per usual in AStar, but discount by a large margin moves that would be out of turn. This is a very hard problem as pointed out, but easily solveable given the following condition:

> Every turn a new path can and will be searched anyway: this is easily
> believable, because until next turn circumstance can easily change. If
> not, those are not really turns as we know them.

If that condition is ok with you, just do the above snippet. Heuristic must be discounted by the same value for all "out of this turn" moves and NOT smoothly (e.g. `Heuristic += (Cost - CanMove) * 100`) i.e. there must be a large difference between "this turn" and "not this turn".